# Check if Time Period Overlaps

Tags: delphi

i have 3 Configurable Time Intervals , right now set to :

```
1 06:00 - 14:30
2 14:30 - 23:00
3 23:00 - 06:00
```

I would like to check if the Time Intervals overlap if the user changes it , and then prevent the change .

But I am not sure how to do this , I googled, I used a bit of IRC , they told me I could do :

```
Start1 < Stop3
Start2 < Stop1
Start3 < Stop2
```

This would work fine until I've set

```
Stop3 = 23:00
Start1 = 00:00
```

Any tips perhaps ?

Thank you

Comment: I think a little more info is needed, do your intervals always cover 24h? Otherwise an overlap could just mean, that there is a longer break, e.g. Stop1 = 14.00; Start2 = 10.00 could be an overlap or a break of 20 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the time periods could extend to the next day, you must add a fictive date.

If your time values are in a `TTime` type, and the testing variables are in a `TDateTime` type:

```
if (StartTime1 > StopTime1) then begin // Extend time to next day
  StartDT1 := StartTime1;
  StopDT1 := DateUtils.IncDay(StopTime1,1);
end
else begin
  StartDT1 := StartTime1;
  StopDT1 := StopTime1;      
end;
```

Do this for all three intervals.

Then it is easy to check for overlap with this test:

```
overlap := (StartDT1 < StopDT2) and (StartDT2 < StopDT1) or
           (StartDT1 < StopDT3) and (StartDT3 < StopDT1) or
           (StartDT2 < StopDT3) and (StartDT3 < StopDT2);
```

Comment: I will accept this, because I provided to little info . And I just realized I am fighting against myself here . 
So I have 3 Shifts, but they all go like 1,2,3 and they all must be connected. Between a Shift there can be no empty time . So I realised that the easiest way to solve is to just check if Stop3=Start1 ,Stop1=Start2,Stop2=Start3 , if yes then it is ok otherwise error , overlapping or space .